# Must have local user to authenticate Samba to AD?

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

I've got a CentOS 5.3 server with Samba running.  I've joined this server to my domain in the hopes of allowing AD users some access to my Samba shares.  I've found that this works, but only as long as the AD username that I'm trying to authenticate with is *also* a local user on the server.  In other words, if I'm trying to access a share, and try to authenticate with the AD username "joe", I get errors unless I create a user named 'joe' on the server.  I don't have to create a matching password or anything....the local user's password is always blank, so I do know that the authentication is actually happening against the AD.

Here's my smb.conf file:

> [global]
>
> ```
>     workgroup = <mydomain>
>     server string = <snip>
>     netbios name = HOME
>     security = ADS
>     realm = <mydomain.com>
>     password server = <snip>
>     auth methods = winbind
>     log level = 1
>     log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
> ```
>
> [amore]
>           path = /var/www/amore
>           browseable = yes
>           writable = yes
>           valid users = DOMAIN\user1 DOMAIN\user2 DOMAIN\user3 DOMAIN\user4

I would assume that my kerberos settings are fine, as I've joined the domain and can use wbinfo to see users and groups.  However, I can provide that info if necessary.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's two separate things, one is not having to duplicate passwords but authenticate passwords from the same central source. The other is not duplicating user accounts but checking them at a central source. You're halfway there, fight! ;) This one might be old but: http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_%26_Active_Directory#Steps

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, Linux uses UID/GID values in its access control sysetm, while the Windows NT operating system family uses Security Identifiers (SIDs) in its access control system.

The Windows Server 2003 R2 Active Directory along with "Services for Unix" (which provides the RFC2307bis schema) can store UID/GID values for each user in the directory and Samba is capable of using these values (or, so I've read-- I've never actually tried it, but multiple docs I've ready say that it works well).

If you're not storing UID/GID values in a directory service then you'll need a mechanism to deterministically map between these two unlike identifier systems. The "idmap" functionality of "winbind" is typically used to perform this mapping. Have a look at the following articles to get some idea of the functionality:

- [Identity Mapping (IDMAP)](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/idmapper.html) from the Samba HOWTO collection
- [Winbind: Use of Domain Accounts](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/winbind.html)
- [Samba & Active Directory](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_%26_Active_Directory): A lot of what you're trying to do

Comment: +1 Winbind (oh the live character check doesn't care for spaces, but the submit check does, doh ;p